# Как решить проблему с региональной принадлежностью сайта, используя домены?

Tags: веб-программирование, joomla, поддомены, домен

Имеется сайт с доменом: site76.ru (где 76 - это регион) в данный момент планируется сделать так, чтобы сайт отображался и по региону 71 (т.е. домен = site71.ru). Целесообразно ли так делать, указывая два домена на один и тот же сайт или лучше воспользоваться поддоменами? (понимаю что выбрать домен сайта сильно привязанный к региону было изначально глупо). Если есть другой способ решения данной проблемы буду рад услышать. Сайт на joomla

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите домен который нужен (site71.ru), привяжите его, укажите в robot и поисковиках как зеркало для основного домена (site76.ru). В web мастере(yandex) проверьте на дубли. Установите редиректы по необходимости.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему проблем возникнуть не должно. Ведь виртуальные хостинги как-то существуют, там тоже куча доменов указывают на один IP-адрес и при этом сайты нормально продвигаются в поисковых системах.